# newrelic-install file missing

Tags: php, newrelic

After I yum install newrelic-php5 wiuthout any errors it does not seem to create the newrelic-install file.  I've tried removing it and reinstalling it with the same issue, used `yum clean` and alos removed the rpm repo and removed any and all traces of newrelic I could find and I still can't get the yum install to also add the newrelic-install file like it is supposed to.

I'm not sure what to do

did a  `find / -name newrelic-install` and it comes up with nothing.

I'm using fedora 17

Any ideas?  Not sure how to troubleshoot this unfortunately.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/php/php-agent-installation-redhat-and-centos

Comment: Yes! I followed them to a tee and I get zero errors. I just don't see that file.  If you ran into this problem, what would you do to troubleshoot it?   My best guess is there is some sort of variable or setting indicating the file was already made somewhere in some file that doesn't have the word 'newrelic' in it (because did a search for all new-relic files) and completley removing newrelic and refolllowing those idiot proof instructions won't repair it because this said file is something out of scope and dealing with installed services... or something.. Idk plz help.

Comment: I would try out Steven's recommendation below for the manual install process. If this doesn't work out, please contact support at New Relic with additional details about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information about your system, log files, etc ... it is difficult to diagnose the actual issue and provide a work around.

In cases where the package manager does not appear to be working correctly you should try the tarball install method.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/php/php-agent-installation-tar-files